# Convergence of a complex sequence $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{m} (1 - 1/a_n^m)$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let the squence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies
$$a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{m} (1 - \frac{1}{a_n^m}),$$ 
and $a_0 = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{m}$, where $\alpha$ is a complex number such that $|\alpha| < 1$.
Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a_n = 1$.

**P.S.** I know a complicated soulution to this question.
Note that $f(x) = 1 + \frac{\alpha}{m} (1 - x^{-m})$ satisfies $f(1) = 1$ and $|f'(1)| = |\alpha| < 1$.
Therefore, $x = 1$ is an attracting fix point of $f$. Denote its basin under $f$ by $A$.
We know $A$ must contain a critical point of $f$.
Next, note that $f$ only have two critical points $0$ and $\infty$ and $f(0) = \infty$, $f(\infty) = a_0$. Consequently, $0$ and $\infty$ both lie on $A$. Hence, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f^n(a_0) = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f^{n+1}(\infty) = 1.$$

I want to know if there is a more elementary method to prove this conclusion.